# Where should I store the static data in android for fastest read?

Tags: java, android

I have a Google Sheets table contains 200 lines and two columns. Column 1 is a string column 2 is an integer. Where should I store this static data to read it later fastest? Should I add the static content to ArrayList by adding in the async task as hardcode or read it from a database or a file?

Comment: Put your data in a file. Put that file in assets directory.

Answer (score 0):

First AsyncTask was deprecated, Second, there are many options to do that like putting them in a file or using Roam or Realm

Answer (score 0):

Storing them in memory will be the fastest approach if you want quick access to the data set and are constantly reading it.

Otherwise re-creating an Array that holds all the data in Pairs when required. This is if you're not accessing it quickly/constantly.

You should make a custom `Pair<K, V>` implementation to parse and access the data in an orderly manner. If you want to retain order use something like a `LinkedList<T>` to store the `Pair<K, V>` results in.